# C++ references to main parameters

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, program-entry-point

I've read [the libc reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html#Program-Arguments) for `int main (int argc, char *argv[])`, as well as  section 3.6.1 "Main function" in the [current working standard of the C++ ISO documentation](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard). I've also read a bunch about references. I understand they cannot be reassigned, that they must be only one layer deep, etc.

That said, why is the standard `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` rather than `int main (int argc, char * &argv)` such that it is an "array"/data block holding the references to the parameters?

What I mean by this is why have an array of arrays (char **argv) that are NOT owned by a program and COULD be changed/moved during run time instead of memory that by its definition cannot be modified without the program's consent and proper handling (for example via signaling)? What am I missing?

Comment: `char * &argv` would be a reference to a single char array, not all of the parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of, consider `char*` to mean `c_string`, and it immediately becomes obvious why you would need `int main(int argc, c_string argv[])` versus `int main(int argc, c_string& argv)`. After all, programs can take more than one parameter.

Since an array of references (if it were allowed) would turn out to hold only a single char per index, since references cannot be used to find the next character (without taking the reference of it, and thus converting it to a pointer), this does not make any sense either.

The assumption that the array of arguments is not owned by the program is simply false. The C standards 1999 and 2011 explicitly say:

> The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall
>   be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program
>   startup and program termination.

And my copy of the C++1y standard draft says nothing to the contrary.

Comment: In this case, is it saying that the last-stored values that the OS knows or the Program, eg. they can be changed but must be put back the way they were at the start at termination OR they can be changed, but on termination they can only be cleaned.

Comment: Also, aren't the parameters character strings with a terminal '\0', if so, isn't that the length rather than just a single character per index? Where a reference only would refer to the first character, but the full cstring would be apparent from the data?

Answer (score 2):

As @Red Alert said you have confused the redeclaration of "main" but I'm going to answer what I think you asked.

The program arguments is provided by the operating system, and thus is not actually owned by the program. Remember that C/C++ is intended to be low level and efficient so extra copies of arguments should be avoided. I have not seen anyone actually change them on a running program but there are several ways in e.g. Linux to retrieve them outside of the program.

Also think of compatibility with C, you have not got the "&" operator in that way in C and the "main" declaration is inherited from C.

Comment: The efficiency part makes sense here since OS could reuse parameters for different programs. Compatibility also seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

First, there's no such thing as "array of references" in C++. The standard explicitly prohibits it (§8.3.2 [dcl.ref]/5):

> There shall be no references to references, no references to arrays of runtime bound, **no arrays of references**, and no pointers to references.

Second, even if there were such a thing, backward compatibility requirements would weigh extremely heavily against such a change, which would break lots and lots of existing code using `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` for no good reason.

Comment: The arrays of references is probably the reason. I'm still not sure from a CS view point why you'd want to structure the parameters that way, but it makes sense within the context of this language.